# Connected to WIFI but no internet

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I've read the tutorial at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Get_the_name_of_the_interface

And as far as I understood the key steps are to run `wpa_supplicant` and then `dhclient`

The output of `wpa_supplicant` contained:

```
...
wlp12s0: WPA: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to ... completed ...
wlp12s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with ... [GTK=TKIP]
...
```

Then I executed:

```
$ sudo iw dev wlp12s0 link
Connected to ... (on wlp12s0)
SSID: ...
freq: ...
...
```

Then:

```
$ sudo dhclient -v wlp12s0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp12s0/00:23:4e:07:a1:e5
Sending on   LPF/wlp12s0/00:23:4e:07:a1:e5
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.67 on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x75d51110)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.67 on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x75d51110)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x69d6c72f)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
Trying recorded lease 192.168.1.67
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

bound: renewal in 42208 seconds.
```

to get an IP.

But sometimes the output of `dhclient` looks so:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp12s0/00:23:4e:07:a1:e5
Sending on   LPF/wlp12s0/00:23:4e:07:a1:e5
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x37f4762)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x37f4762)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x37f4762)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.67 on wlp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x62477f03)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.67 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.67 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.67 -- renewal in 37520 seconds.
```

Does it mean that the IP `192.168.1.67` was assigned or not? Sorry, I don't know how the successful output looks. Anyway I cannot ping any website after that. But I was able to ping it from another PC in my home:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.67
PING 192.168.1.67 (192.168.1.67) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.67: icmp_seq=206 ttl=64 time=213 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.67: icmp_seq=327 ttl=64 time=318 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.67: icmp_seq=480 ttl=64 time=317 ms
```

After it completed (It took ca. 5 minutes. Is it ok?) I ran `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:23:82:98:53
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:40841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:3067719 (3.0 MB)  TX bytes:3067719 (3.0 MB)

wlp12s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:4e:07:a1:e5
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:341 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:119856
          TX packets:837 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:23190 (23.1 KB)  TX bytes:86896 (86.8 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000

wlp12s0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:4e:07:a1:e5
          inet addr:169.254.8.210  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp12s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Kazak"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: D4:21:22:25:E3:04
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp9s0    no wireless extensions.
```

But no internet connection:

```
$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

What am I missing?

P.S. Wired connection works.

Comment: And have you got that ip?
Show  results of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`

Comment: @DevilaN I've added their outputs to the question.

Comment: 169.254.8.210 address is from default pool when there is no DHCP or valid DHCP response. You should investigate whether your dhcp server is working and is able to correctly assign you IP address.

Comment: I can connect without any problems to this access point from a windows-notebook. I thought I have control only over DHCP client, not the server?

Comment: try running dhclient with -v parameter to get verbose output

Comment: @DevilaN I've updated the question with the output of dhclient

Comment: This can be wrong on so many levels. Can you use knoppix on pendrive as live distribution and boot into it to check whether it is properly getting IP address and then we can decide whether it is problem with your DHCP server or configuration of you current distribution.

Comment: I'm using kubuntu 16.04 live usb. But I couldn't use it unconfigured because I had to install a driver for my wifi adapter.

Comment: Add Google DNS to your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @GAD3R
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN